# Why im getting an error when creating an event in my new class?

Tags: c#, events, generics

I didn't understand the erorr message and what to do to fix it and why it happen.
This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    class BackgroundWebCrawling
    {
        public string f;
        int counter = 0;
        List<string> WebSitesToCrawl;
        int MaxSimultaneousThreads;
        BackgroundWorker mainBackGroundWorker;
        BackgroundWorker secondryBackGroundWorker;
        WebcrawlerConfiguration webcrawlerCFG;
        List<WebCrawler> webcrawlers;
        int maxlevels;
        public event EventHandler<BackgroundWebCrawling> ProgressEvent;
```

The error is on the ProgressEvent

> Error 1   The type 'GatherLinks.BackgroundWebCrawling' cannot be used as
>   type parameter 'TEventArgs' in the generic type or method
>   'System.EventHandler'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'GatherLinks.BackgroundWebCrawling' to
>   'System.EventArgs'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `EventHandler<T>` signature is (at least, originally) intended for scenarios where the `args` (in the common `sender` / `args` pattern) is some subclass of `EventArgs`. As such, there is a `where T : EventArgs` constraint (edit - as ByteBlast notes: until .NET 4.5, where the [constraint is removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

`BackgroundWebCrawling` is *not* an `EventArgs`. Besides which, there would be no point sending it as the `args`, as you are presumably already sending it (`this`) as the `sender`.

If you have no interesting args to send, just use the non-generic `EventHandler`, and send `EventArgs.Empty`.